# Managing decimal numbers php (0.576 -> 0.57 and not 0.58)

Tags: php, decimal

**My code:**

```
$number = "0.576";
$commaFix = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

**The problem:**

I need my decimal number (0.576) to be a decimal number with only 2 numbers behind the comma. Only I need the number not to be idk if it's correct english but 'rounded' down instead of up... So it has to become 0.57 and not 0.58 (the 0.58 is what it does now).

Thanks for the efford!

Comment: See [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) Specifically the `mode` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that using some math and the php floor function

```
$number = '0.576';
$number = floor($number*100)/100;
```